# Background on phpBB forum stops at bottom of screen rather than page

Tags: css

My phpBB theme is Supernova and originally does not have a background image.

[WTG Forum](http://forum.webtechglobal.co.uk/index.php)

I'm using the same image as the header which does have a repeated background. I originally copied the same CSS for the header into body{}.

```
background: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/blue/headerbg.png") repeat bottom #0f518f;
```

Since then I have spent an hour trying everything I could find through Google including fixing the background and putting the background CSS into html{}. Funny thing is when I created an image 2000 x 2000 to explore the issue there was no change!

Also if you go to source and remove the background color which is #000000. It corrects the issue. When I done that I thought hey I've found the solution. Edited the CSS, uploaded and refreshed the style. Just saying so you know I'm not failing to applying changes. I think I've done this over 100 times this morning.

This happens in all browsers too and any help with it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I love it when this happens. I'm about to finish the question and submit.

I decided to think more on the source edit that appeared to fix the problem. I realized I may not have removed every background color line.

Sure enough common.css and colors.css both have background. The browser handles it in an interesting way. Applying one stylesheets rules up until the bottom of the visitors screen. Potentially something to do with one .css file having html, body{} and the other has them seperate.